# What is the best way to transfer text files from one computer to another as they are generated?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a program that is generating text files into a directory. I want it so that all the text files added to this directory are automatically and immediately uploaded to a directory on another computer, which is not on the same network.

An important factor is the latency: the computer which receives the text files will be using these text files "live", so a low delay will be optimal. Of course, there will be measures to put in place to have a stagger (of a constant x seconds) to reasonably account for the delay between transmission and reception of these text files.

Would some sort of automated FTP transfer be the best way? Recommendations for programs and set-ups would be very helpful.

Comment: Specifying the OS would help.

Comment: Of course, sorry, it's Windows (XP).

Comment: You are pretty much limited to using a file transfer protocol like FTP

Answer (score 0):

Setup a shared drive on the machine generating the text file, and have the shared drive point to the folder on the computer that will be reading the files. That way as the files are generated they will be written *directly* to the target computer. Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: How would I go about doing this on Windows? Would this work for computers not on the same network?

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar It would only work for computers on different networks if you had something that connects the two networks: I recommend a VPN of some type. Can you provide more info of how they are networked?

Comment: As of now, they are currently independent from one another - no connection between both. I could set up a VPN if needs be.

Comment: Well I recommend OpenVPN, once that is done and verified working then, share out a folder on computer be to everyone (I know, but you really don't have a choice), and map a drive to that folder on your text generating computer.

Comment: If they are not on the same network then a shared drive isn't a soltion.

Comment: @Ramhound You can have shared drive over vpn, the vpn puts them on the same network.